# How to persise an image in PostgreSQL using Delphi Tokyo

Tags: image, postgresql, delphi

I'm using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO team (name, photo) VALUES (:name, :photo);
```

I already have an image loaded at the TImage component and a Bytea field at the "people" table.

Does anyone could help me?

Comment: Not entirely sure if Postgre is different, but you should be able to get a stream asking the `TField` to `CreateBlobStream`. Use this stream to stream the Images data to your field.

Comment: Hard to say. We don't know your client library. If it's serious enough, it can save a binary string by BLOB accessor.

Answer (score 0):

An example of code to insert an image into a Postgres BYTEA field would be:

```
procedure TForm1.SaveBlobClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   stream:  TMemoryStream;//TBlobStream TStream
   format: integer;

begin
   with query1 do
      begin
      sql.Clear;
      stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      sql.Add('INSERT INTO tmp_blob (image) VALUES (:blob);');
      TmpJpg.SaveToStream(stream);
      ParamByName('blob').LoadFromStream(stream, ftGraphic ); 
      ExecSql;
      stream.Free;

      end;
end;
```

And to read a image:

```
procedure TForm1.BLoadBlobClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   stream: TStream;//TMemoryStream
   g : TGraphic;
begin
   with query1 do
      begin
      close;
      sql.clear;
      sql.add('SELECT * FROM tmp_blob LIMIT 1' );
      Open;
      Stream := query1.CreateBlobStream(fieldByName('image') , bmRead );
      tmpJpg.LoadFromStream(stream);
      image1.Picture.Bitmap := tmpJpg.toBitmap;

      close;
      Stream.Free;
      end;
end;
```

NOTE: I use a `TJpegImage` component , from `SynGdiPlus` library, to load and save the image